# how to make a field mandatory inside if else condition in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i written a jquery code to show ,hide text box depends upon value. so now i want to make that text box mandatory when it appear.

the code am using is below.

```
document.getElementById('other').style.display = 'none';

$("#donate").change(function(){
    var selected = $(this).val();
    if(selected  == 'item') {
       document.getElementById('other').style.display = 'block';
     } else {
        document.getElementById('other').style.display = 'none';
     }
});
```

how to make it mandatory. please anyone help me out to do this

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#donate").change(function(){

 if($("#other").is(":hidden")==false)
    {
        if($('#other').val()==""){
        alert("Field is required");
        return;
    }


 });
```

Answer (score 0):

On submit button you can do as follows

```
var donate = $("#donate").val();
if(donate == 'item') {
   var item = $('#other').val();
   if(item == ''){
      alert('item is required.');
      return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: i can't use it on submit button. is there any other option ?, is not possible to use it in my code itself?

Answer (score 0):

make some changes in your code

```
document.getElementById('other').style.display = 'none';

$("#donate").change(function(){
    var selected = $(this).val();
    if(selected  == 'item') {
       document.getElementById('other').style.display = 'block';
       document.getElementById('other').getAttribute('required',true);
       or
document.getElementById('other').getAttribute('required','required');
     } else {
        document.getElementById('other').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('other').getAttribute('required',false);
     }
});
```

i Hope it will help you now

Comment: i can't call function on submit button. Thats why am struggling. can you tell how to do it in hide , show function itself

Comment: Yes you can do it write this code in show and hide block of your code .document.getElementById('other').setAttribute('required',true);document.getElementById('other').setAttribute('required',false)

Comment: inside if condition?

Comment: or you can write document.getElementById('other').setAttribute('required','required');

Comment: where should i write this code?, i tried it in if else condition and getting error

Comment: that hidden text box is visible while loading the page itself